# The Rails way for databases: person may_have (has_one ?) account

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out most of the database design and normalization before I do much for my current project. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with database design, so it's a fairly slow process. One of the issues I'm trying to figure out is what's the best way to deal with a situation where one table may, or may not, be associated with another table.

A little background will help clear the question: I'm building a web application, using Rails 3.2, that helps manage races. People will be able to create accounts (/user accounts), host races, and manage the various aspects.

One thing is that the participants in a given race may or may not be users. In fact, we can assume that most of them will not be users. But for those who are, it would be nice to be able to link to their profiles (and, going the other way, link from their profiles to the races they've participated in).

It's sort of like blog posts where people can post anonymous comments, but if they do decide to log in and use their account then it's linked with the post in various ways.

I've searched for a while, but haven't really found solutions. I figure the way to do it is to have the Participants model note "has_one UserParticipation", which would usually be nil.

Is that a valid solution?
 Is there a better way to go about this?

Here's a small diagram I threw together in Paint to concisely show the issue: [image: database_issue]

Question 2:
This is a little less important, but I figured I'd ask it in the same question because I've already posted the relevant question: several things will reference participants, is there any reason to set up a composite {Race_ID, Participant_Number} super key rather than always reference it using "race.participants"? (As far as I can tell, these would work very similarly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be over thinking it a bit. If I am following you correctly, this is a simple entity relationship diagram I whipped up in Dia:

[image: simple erd]

Some explanation on the assoications of a *User* to *Participants*:

A Participant will have the `belongs_to :user` association, which is `nil` if there is no associated User.

A User will have the `has_many :participants` association, allowing none to many Participants relations. If there are none, a user instance will have `user.participants` equal an empty array.

As to the second question, you would only need to use both keys if you are querying for a specific participant for specific race, e.g. `where participant_id = 7 and race_id = 4`.

Comment: Yeah, that extra table was kind of unnecessary, you're right. Actually your model helps clear a few things up about how Rails works with databases.

So in the user model, when I have User has_many participants (perhaps renamed participations), I wouldn't use "has_many participations :through Races" because that would imply that it was their Race (and so they hosted it), right? It would just simply be "has_many participations"? It seems to make sense now.

Comment: Anyway, I'm accepting your answer. It's very similar to the way I originally thought out parts of my database, and I think I got sidetracked thinking "if my old database design professor saw this he'd kill me" with so many possibilities for null values in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

So a race has many participants (some of whom are users), and a participant has many races (hopefully :-).

Taking the user part of things out of the picture for a moment, this is a simple many-to-many relationship which Rails handles beautifully with `has_and_belongs_to_many` on both Race and Participant models, described here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association.  Another alternative, not necessary in your case is `has_many :through` which creates a first-class model backed by the join table.  But what you have described makes this unnecessary.

The relationship between User and participant is one-to-one, and conditional.  It's not clear to me if you can be a user without being a participant but if you have a User who is a  Participant, you want them related.  This is a `:has_one` relation.

The cool part of Rails that I'll bet you're looking for is that relationships can be conditional, so in this case a Participant has_one User conditionally.  The linked Rails Guide document describes how to define all of this.

Comment: If it is the case that to host a race you must be a user, then mguymon is correct in asserting that Race belongs_to User, and User has_many Races.